# search a json string and return previous index in observable array

Tags: knockout.js

I have an observable array containing JSON data returned from an ajax query:

```
    this.navList = ko.observableArray();
```

poplutated it looks like this:

```
    "navList":[{"id":"50000"},{"id":"50001"},{"id":"50003"},{"id":"50006"},{"id":"50009"},{"id":"50011"},{"id":"50017"},{"id":"50018"},{"id":"50019"},{"id":"50020"},{"id":"50021"},{"id":"50022"},{"id":"50023"},{"id":"50024"},{"id":"50025"},{"id":"50026"},{"id":"50027"},{"id":"50028"},{"id":"50029"}]
```

And I have an observable that is populated from another ajax call representing the current record:

```
    this.idNumber = ko.observable("");
```

And it looks like this:

```
    "idNumber":50003
```

I am trying to search through the array for this string and then return the previous index:

```
    var indexofnav = vm.navList.indexOf(vm.idNumber());
    var previous = indexofnav - 1;
    alert(vm.navList()[previous].id());
```

Currently I can manually set previous to the number 2 instead of indexofnav -1 and get the correct answer of 500003 but the indexOf is coming up as -1.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JLREk/2/):

```
var navList = ko.observableArray([{"id":"50000"},{"id":"50001"},{"id":"50003"},{"id":"50006"},{"id":"50009"},{"id":"50011"},{"id":"50017"},{"id":"50018"},{"id":"50019"},{"id":"50020"},{"id":"50021"},{"id":"50022"},{"id":"50023"},{"id":"50024"},{"id":"50025"},{"id":"50026"},{"id":"50027"},{"id":"50028"},{"id":"50029"}]);

var obs = ko.observable({"idNumber":"50003"});

var memberInArray = ko.utils.arrayFirst(navList(), function(element){
    return element.id == obs().idNumber;
})
var index = navList().indexOf(memberInArray);
var resultIndex = index - 1;
```

When you are looking for the item in the array, you need to look by comparing the id values. this.idNumber will be an entirely different object from any of those already existing in the array, and so indexOf will return -1.

Comment: It worked!  I changed this line: return element.id == obs().idNumber;    to this:  return element.id() == self.idNumber(); which I assume is because I was using ko.mapping.fromJS which converted id to observable.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your "indexOf" cannot work.
Your array is an array of **objects** not an array of values, yet you are doing your indexOf call with only a value.

Change your indexOf to look for an object with an "Id" property, or change your array to be an array of values like "[ '50000', '50001', '50002', ...  ]"